# How to find the nearest 25th or 10th day for a given date and adds it to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Our team is developing a Loan System for teachers where their amortization is deducted on their payday, the 10th and 25th day of the month. Upon submitting the online application form, there is a column in the loan table for the `dateapplied` which stores the date when the teacher applied for the loan. What we want is to find the nearest 25th or 10th day of the month based from `dateapplied` and store it into another column which is `startdeduct`.

For example, the faculty applied for a loan today `(2015-10-23)` which will be stored in `dateapplied`. At the same time I want to store `(2015-10-25)` in `startdeduct` which is when will the deductions will start.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What you tried yet? show us your code.

Comment: and what if it is applied on 17th/18th/27th of October. What would be your desired `startdeduct`

Comment: `startdeduct` should be greater than `dateapplied` or just the closest value? For example, `dateapplied = 2015-10-26`. `startdeduct` should be `2015-10-25` or `2015-11-10`?

Comment: @Utsav if applied on 17th and 18th, startdeduct will be 10/25. if applied on 27th, startdeduct will be 11/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT dateapplied,
 (CASE WHEN (DAY(dateapplied) > 25) THEN 
     STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dateapplied, '%Y%m'), '10'), '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  WHEN (DAY(dateapplied) > 10) THEN 
     STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dateapplied, '%Y%m'), '25'), '%Y%m%d')
  ELSE 
     STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dateapplied, '%Y%m'), '10'), '%Y%m%d')
  END) AS `startdeduct`
FROM example
```

or even a little shorter

```
SELECT dateapplied,
   (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dateapplied, '%Y%m'), 
   IF(DAY(dateapplied) BETWEEN 11 AND 25, '25', '10')), '%Y%m%d') + 
   INTERVAL IF(DAY(dateapplied) > 25, 1, 0) MONTH) AS `startdeduct`
FROM example
```

Statement to update table:

```
UPDATE mydb.loan SET startdeduct = 
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dateapplied, '%Y%m'), 
    IF(DAY(dateapplied) BETWEEN 11 AND 25, '25', '10')), '%Y%m%d') + 
    INTERVAL IF(DAY(dateapplied) > 25, 1, 0) MONTH)
```

Comment: Hi. I want to then insert the 'startdeduct' to the actual table. So how should my query be? INSERT mydb.loan (startdeduct) values (???)?

Comment: I think you need an update for the table, see my edits

Answer (score 0):

If `startdeduct` date is greater than `dateapplied` you can use something like this:

```
SELECT dateapplied,
       IF(date_day > 25,
          str_to_date(concat(DATE_FORMAT(date_next, '%Y%m'), '10'), '%Y%m%d'),
          IF(date_day > 10,
             str_to_date(concat(DATE_FORMAT(dateapplied, '%Y%m'), '25'), '%Y%m%d'),
             str_to_date(concat(DATE_FORMAT(dateapplied, '%Y%m'), '10'), '%Y%m%d'))) startdeduct
  FROM (SELECT dateapplied,
               extract(DAY FROM dateapplied) date_day,
                    adddate(dateapplied, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) date_next
          FROM (SELECT str_to_date('2015-10-26', '%Y-%m-%d') dateapplied
                UNION ALL
                SELECT str_to_date('2015-10-17', '%Y-%m-%d') dateapplied
                UNION ALL
                SELECT str_to_date('2015-10-18', '%Y-%m-%d') dateapplied
                UNION ALL
                SELECT str_to_date('2015-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d') dateapplied
                UNION ALL
                SELECT str_to_date('2015-10-11', '%Y-%m-%d') dateapplied) dates) ndates
```

Inner subquery is just data, next - some precalculated values for IF statements.

Output of this query:

```
| dateapplied | startdeduct | 
----------------------------- 
| 2015-10-26  | 2015-11-10  | 
| 2015-10-17  | 2015-10-25  | 
| 2015-10-18  | 2015-10-25  | 
| 2015-10-01  | 2015-10-10  | 
| 2015-10-11  | 2015-10-25  |
```